# How to query database with conditional expression in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-1.8

I have three models: Business, Offers and OfferPlan:
Business:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name_of_business = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Offers:

```
class Offers(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, related_name="business_offer",
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subtext = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

OfferPlan:

```
class OfferPlan(models.Model):
    WEEKDAYS = [
        (1, _("Monday")),
        (2, _("Tuesday")),
        (3, _("Wednesday")),
        (4, _("Thursday")),
        (5, _("Friday")),
        (6, _("Saturday")),
        (7, _("Sunday")),
    ]
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offers, related_name="business_offer_plan",
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    weekday = models.IntegerField(
        choices=WEEKDAYS,
    )
    from_hour = models.TimeField()
    to_hour = models.TimeField()
```

I have a ListView which search for businesses open based on different params such as city, category etc. I also want to now search by weekday, say which business is open on Monday will be displayed and which are not wont be displayed on that day. Weekday information is stored in OfferPlan and there could be multiple timings for the offers that day in OfferPlan table, but I want to query (filter, exclude) the businesses who has even a single entry on that weekday number.

Here is my ListView:

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'search/search.html'
    model = Business

    def get_queryset(self):
        # queryset = Business.objects.filter(business_address__city=AppLocations.objects.first().city)
        if 'city' in self.request.GET:
            queryset = Business.objects.filter(business_address__city=self.request.GET.get('city'))

        if 'category' in self.request.GET:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category__code=self.request.GET.get('category'))

        # if 'date' not in self.request.GET:
        #     queryset = B
        raise
        return queryset
```

How could this be possible? Also looked into https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/ but not able to figure out.

Thanks

---

### Update 1

---

After researching more in the web, I figured out this is how it could be achieved, but need to know for sure from other Django enthusiasts here that it is right.

```
queryset.filter(business_offer__business_offer_plan__weekday=1).annotate(count_entry=Count('business_offer__business_offer_plan__weekday')).filter(count_entry__gt=1)
```

---

### Solution

---

Jefferson's solution was tagged as right answer as it provided more insights, about which query is fast and what wrong was with my previous update, so here is the proper solution to which we both agreed:

`queryset.filter(business_offer__business_offer_plan__weekday=1).annotate(count_entry=Count('business_offer__business_offer_plan__weekday')).filter(count_entry__gte=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_query(weekday):
    businesses = Business.objects.filter(business_offer__in=Offers.objects.filter(
        business_offer_plan__in=OfferPlan.objects.filter(weekday=weekday))).distinct()
    return businesses
```

There's a heavy query, but it works.

Comment: Thanks, but please look at my `update 1` and tell me if that is a good way too?

Comment: @Maverick Yeah, my and yours queries wrong :D In your query fix:
last filter should be "filter(count_entry__gte=1)"

Comment: @Maverick fixed my query (just forget add "distinct" in end).

Comment: mine will work even without adding gte, as I am simply looking for greater than 1, greater than equals doesnt matter, what say? :)

Comment: @Maverick If business have 1 offerplan for this day it will be not in query result

Comment: @Maverick Your query faster x2 (on tables with more than 100k elements its proc in 0.004s in my pc)

Comment: I wrote a test to check, so, even if a business has one offer plan it will be returned. Regarding your second comment, you mean to say my query is faster ? How did you test it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153597/discussion-between-jefferson-houp-and-maverick).

Answer (score 1):

There's no conditional expression here - and your annotation is much too complicated. You just need an additional filter.

```
queryset.filter(business_offer__business_offer_plan__weekday=self.request.GET['weekday'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wont work as expected, until you call it like this, `queryset.filter(business_offer__business_offer_plan__weekday=self.request.GET['weekday']).distinct()`, as otherwise it will return multiple instances of the same business and offers.